# WPF MVVM - Refresh Treeview

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I have created a Treeview in WPF MVVM (Project is using MVVM Light).

When I add a data to a DataTemplate of the Treeview, I want to reload the entire treeview. For this I am sending a Message from my data entry viewmodel to my treeview view model.

Though the message is recieved, the tree doesnt get refreshed. I called LoadChildren on each node again, and used RaisePropertyChanged as well but the data didnt get updated.

Comment: As usual: without code, we can't do much. Please post the relevant parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TreeView` is bound to a hierarchical collection in your `ViewModel`, and it has a property name, e.g. `TreeViewData`. Assuming your `ViewModel` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, simply call the `PropertyChanged` handler for property `TreeViewData`. This will completely refresh the `TreeView`.

Comment: He is using mvvm light so its viewModel has to implement ViewModelBase, which already implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: great, then instruct ViewModelBase to raise the change notification

Comment: Hi thanks for the hint. actually I was raising Refreshed events on the Children property of my TreeViewModel, but the parent property wasnt Raising the property Changed. After including it the tree is getting refreshed. Also sorry I wasnt able to post code. Its my company code and I am not allowed to post it online. I was creating a repro before which the code worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on the fact you are using Mvvm light, since you did not provide code I will just state the obvious and it might solve your issues.

Is your viewmodel implementing the ViewModelBase interface? (which implements INotifiedPropertyChanged)

I never used TreeViews but assuming it's using a collection as its datatemplate, you have to call RaisePropertyChanged on the collection whenever you add/remove an item and also whenever an item changes. Calling RaisePropertyChanged only in the "set" of the collection won't be enough.